# Boost.Thread Linking - boost_thread vs. boost_thread-mt

Tags: ubuntu, g++, linker, boost-thread

It's not clear to me what linking options exist for the [Boost.Thread 1.34.1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/doc/html/thread.html) library.  I'm on Ubuntu 8.04 and I've found that when using either `boost_thread` or `boost_thread-mt` during linking both compile and run, but I don't see any documentation on these or any other linking options in above link.

What Boost.Thread linking options are available and what do they mean?

Comment: Why are you building 1.34.1 instead of 1.43.1?

Comment: @DeadMG:  Because that's what comes with Ubuntu 8.04 and I don't have the option of compiling and installing a newer version.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well...

The first amusing thing is that the `-mt` modifier in the name is to indicate the library is Ok for multithreading. Which could lead us to believe that `boost_thread` (without this modifier) could be multithread-unsafe...

But the real thing is that (as seen on my own Ubuntu 10.04 box), `boost_thread` is a soft link to `boost_thread-mt`, which means the two are one and the same.

If you want to verify it, you can open a console on your ubuntu (make the console fullscreen because the names are long), then type:

```
cd /usr/lib
```

to move to the directory where the Boost libraries are. And then:

```
ls -l ./libboost_thread*
```

Which will list all the files starting with `libboost_thread`, with additionnal information. The result will be something like:

```
[...] ./libboost_thread.a
[...] ./libboost_thread-mt.a -> libboost_thread.a
```

As you can see, `libboost_thread.a` is a static library, and `libboost_thread-mt.a` is a soft link to `libboost_thread.a`

Answer (score 9):

For a detailed reference of boost library naming scheme, see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming