# Multithreading Boost libraries missing

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to compile a program with boost libraries. It uses `date_time`, `thread`, `system` and `filesystem` libraries. All files of the program compile well, but in the end of the process I get these things:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem-mt
```

I presume `-mt` stands for 'Multithreading'. But I don't know where to get them on my operating system.

Ubuntu 14.10, Boost v1.57
Any hint will do. Thank you for helping! ;)

Comment: It is my understanding that the `-mt` (multithreading) versions of the boost libraries are redundant because all versions of the library are now "multithreading". So it is possible your distro has stopped shipping the `-mt` version (Apparently they were just symlinks to the "normal" libraries anyway): http://stackoverflow.com/a/3031843/3807729

Comment: Yes, it's true. Solved.